# Working with Affine groups of degree 1 in sagemath

Tags: group-theory, sagemath

Let $G$ be the affine group of order $1$ over $\mathbb{R}$, i.e., $G$ is the set of functions

$$T_{a,b}: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}, \ T_{a,b} (x) = ax + b$$

Where $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$ and $a \neq 0$ and the group operation given by the composition of functions.

We defined several subsets of G:

$$
\begin{align}
N &= \big \{ T_{1,b} \in G \mid b \in \mathbb{R} \big\} \\
A &= \big \{ T_{a,0} \in G \mid a \in \mathbb{R}, a \neq 0 \big \} \\
H &= \big \{ T_{1,b} \in G \mid b \in \mathbb{Z} \big \}
\end{align}
$$

I want to approach this question using sagemath 9.4 but running into issues.

`G = AffineGroup(1, RR)`

The above code snippet is what I'm using to as a start. However, documentation on working with the group with that degree isn't helpful.
But I am curious if there is a way to access the elements of the group and manipulate them.

Comment: Are you familiar with the documentation [here](https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/groups/sage/groups/affine_gps/group_element.html)? Do you have a specific problem in mind you're trying to compute?

Comment: @HallaSurvivor Is there a way to generate the sets of N, H or A in my question?

Comment: The above sets are infinite, so what does it mean to "generate" them? Above, @HallaSurvivor is explicitly asking two questions, please answer these questions. (In comment at least, but it would be best to edit the question to address both questions.)

Comment: @HallaSurvivor Sorry this is so late. I have read that documentation before posting here. I didn't get anywhere with it. And to clarify, I want to be able to make subset/subgroups of the affine group above.